# How do I stick an image to the bottom of the visible screen, and be centered?

Tags: css, center, sticky

I have a website, and I need to have an image centered at the bottom of the visible page.
So in any screen size, the image will still be at the bottom, and centered.

Comment: Left 50% does not put it to the center for my link. testing-zone-51.blogspot.com

Comment: since you are a new user here please select the best answer for a problem as the accepted answer when your problem is solved.It helps in pointing the others to the solution that worked for you and gives reputation to the answerer

Answer (score 30, accepted):

using pure css you can achieve this in all new browsers

```
.fix{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    left:50%;
}
<img src="yourimagepath" class="fix"/>
```

and for IE6 you can use `position:absolute;` instead of fixed. This positions the image on the bottom of the page but, as you scroll up, the image will scroll with the page. Unfortunately `position:fixed` in not supported in IE6.

Comment: IF position:absolute works, why bother using position:fixed in newer browsers?

Comment: @xandy: Fixed is the position of an object in relation to the browser window.
Absolute is the position of an object in relation to its containing element

Comment: @shawn: i saw ur code. try using ARR class on the image inside the div and not on the div

Comment: Pankaj Kumar, I put the code:

.ARR{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    left:50%;
    }

But it's still not centered

Comment: @Shawn use an outside div that has `bottom: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; text-align: center` and put the image in there without any additional CSS. That should center it.

Comment: Pankaj Kumar I see the problem was not factoring the image's width into the centering

Answer (score 4):

You should put it into a div and then, imagining your image is 500px wide:

```
div.className{
position:absolute;
margin-left: -250px; /* very important for the image to be centered */
left:50%;
bottom:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Old question but here is the best solution I came up with. Put the image in a container div, the div is positioned at the bottom of the screen and the image is centered inside of it. The div has a set width of 100% so the image can center properly. For the `margin:auto;` to work the image must be displayed as a table element with the `display:table;`

Using `display:table;` means you don't have to set a fixed width to the element that you want centered.

```
    <style>
    .sticky-image-wrapper{
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .sticky-image-wrapper img{
        display: table;
        position: relative;
        margin: auto;
   }
   </style>

    <div class="sticky-image-wrapper">
       <img src="myimage.jpg" />
    </di>
```